# Alsa - how can I tell my default audio output is card 2 and device 0, not hdmi?

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio, vlc, configure

How can I tell my system default sound output is card 2 and device 0, and not card 2 device 3 or 7 or 1?

I did this, but no sound.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Device [C-Media USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ cat /etc/asound.conf
#pcm.!default { 
#  type plug; 
#  slave { pcm "hw:2" } 
#} 
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 2
    device 0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you find that your sound cards keep switching indices, you won't be able to hardcode `defaults.pcm.card 2` in `/etc/asound.conf`. One (complex) approach might work, is to configure the sound kernel modules with your desired priority.

This approach is described in [Debian Bug #614113](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614113#40):

> 1. run `alsamixer`;
> 2. use F6 and research available sound devices
> 3. set correct levels for playing on devices;
> 4. run some sound player that allow select sound devices (`audacious` for example);
> 5. play with you sound devices (with repeating steps 2,3) and decide what should be 
>      default;
> 6. exit `alsamixer` and player;
> 7. login as root;
> 8. run `lsmod | grep snd` and try to understood what modules corresponds to physical sound devices;
> 9. if unsure that you correctly determine modules on step 2:
>      go to `/sys/module` and inspect all directories wich names begins with "snd". This directories names exactly as modules. If you will see "drivers" directory in 
>      inspected directory - then name of inspected directory is name of module that corresponds to physical sound device. Remember (wrote in notepad) all such modules.
> 10. run 
>       `modinfo <module name> | grep desc`
>       for each module that yo found at steps 2 and 3. Read descriptions and
>       make decidion about priorities of this modules. This will be priorities of
>       corresponding sound devices.
> 11. go to `/etc/modprobe.d`;
> 12. create `snd_cards_priorities.conf`;
> 13. write to snd_cards_priorities.conf something like this:
>
>     ```
>     alias snd-card-0 <module for highest priority card>
>     options <module for highest priority card> index=0
>     alias snd-card-1 <module for lower priority card>
>     options <module for lower priority card> index=1
>     ```
> 14. save file;
> 15. restart alsa with 
>       `/usr/sbin/alsa force-reload`
>       command;
> 16. run 
>       `cat /proc/asound/cards`
>       command and check that sound devices are in correct order
>       (device #0 has highest priority);
> 17. repeat steps 9, 10 several times and check that sound devices order is not
>       changing;
> 18. exit root;
> 19. run `alsamixer` and configure you default sound device, exit `alsamixer`.
> 20. use you favorite sound player to test you new configuration.

Comment: You can find the module more easily with `cat /proc/asound/modules` (Cf. https://superuser.com/a/1013451/149452).

Answer (score 5):

To set the default device, you should not redefine the `default` device but simply put the following into `/etc/asound.conf`:

```perl
defaults.pcm.card 2      # or better "PCH"
defaults.pcm.device 0
```

This will work only for programs that actually use a default device without explicitly specifying a device.
If some program like PulseAudio or VLC has been configured for some specific output device, you must change that configuration.

Comment: This worked for me with card 1, but not with PCH, although PCH seems indeed name of card 1.

Comment: Before modifying `/etc` for global change as root, it can be applied immediately to one specific user by putting said lines in `~/.asoundrc`.